# Facebook opengraph. Meta tags, localhost, custom actions, and testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

This is a series of questions about implementation with the Facebook open graph.

So, I make a query to the api as such:  `$this->facebook->api('me/namespace:action', 'post', $args );`

My first query is where do posts appear? For example if I make a call with the parameters as follows:

```
    $args = array(
            //'message'   => 'I just posted a pub review at PubJudge.com',
        'website'=>'www.pubjudge.com',
        'user'=>current_url(),
        'link'      => 'http://www.pubjudge.com/',
        'caption'   => 'Independent, social, pub reviews.'
    );
```

The post appears on my timeline under 'Activity'

As far as I understand, if a user explicitly shares an action it will appear on the timeline. Is this correct?

Is "fb:explicitly_shared" a parameter that should be passed in the $args array?

Next comes Facebooks custom meta data. In this case my obect is a user, and I pass their URL through the $args array. Facebook then scrapes this array to get data from the custom meta tags on this link. Is this correct?
Does this url have to be the url from which the action is initiated? Can I not have a page on my website which simply generates custom meta tags based on a $_GET variable - this way I can keep all this complicated Facebook stuff independent of the main site.

Does anyone know why Facebook gets data for open graph actions like this anyway?

Finally because Facebook scrapes data like this I cannot test this functionality on my localhost. (I could do but it'd be very complex) What I have opted for instead is a testing.domain.com address to test my website and this functionality whilst having domain.com as my main live stable site.

I have also created two apps.. my main app, and a testing app because if I use my main app I have to change the site url to testing.domain.com which then breaks my stable site. Is this a suitable approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand, if a user explicitly shares an action it will
>   appear on the timeline. Is this correct?

Yes, that's correct. You can find more information at the [Facebook docs for explicit sharing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/explicit-sharing/).  To be noted from the docs, you'll have to mark your action as able to explicitly share on your app dashboard and Facebook will have to approve it.

> Is "fb:explicitly_shared" a parameter that should be passed in the
>   $args array?

Yes.

> Next comes Facebooks custom meta data. In this case my obect is a
>   user, and I pass their URL through the $args array. Facebook then
>   scrapes this array to get data from the custom meta tags on this link.
>   Is this correct?

Yes, Facebook scrapes the URL you pass so they can get data from the OG tags at that link.

> Does this url have to be the url from which the action is initiated?
>   Can I not have a page on my website which simply generates custom meta
>   tags based on a $_GET variable - this way I can keep all this
>   complicated Facebook stuff independent of the main site.

No, it does not have to be the url from which the action is generated.  You can have a separate page on your website, and in fact you can even use javascript to redirect users who land on that page to a more appropriate page.

> Does anyone know why Facebook gets data for open graph actions like
>   this anyway?

That's probably a deeper question than you realize. In short, they are trying to create a semantic web. The long answer would be an essay.

> Finally because Facebook scrapes data like this I cannot test this
>   functionality on my localhost.

You can use reverse proxy which works in most cases (I've seen problems with photos if you are using a port for the reverse proxy). Not very complicated. Something like the following works well:

```
ssh -nN -f -R externalhost.com:49080:localhost:80 your@credentials.biz
```

> I have also created two apps.. my main app, and a testing app because
>   if I use my main app I have to change the site url to
>   testing.domain.com which then breaks my stable site. Is this a
>   suitable approach?

Yes, that's normal. We typically have a development app (localhost), a staging app (external host for testing), and a production app.

Comment: Perfect answer ! Much appreciated ! I will look into reverse proxys. I suppose my only additional query is as to whether having the scrapeable pages 'elsewhere' per se is a good implementation..?

Comment: For some apps like games where we just want to redirect the user back to the main game page, we use a dedicated path (e.g. http://www.myapp.com/opengraph).  But let's say you were selling shoes.  You'd probably want each product page to be an opengraph object so the OG tags would be a part of each page of your main site.  Hope that helps.

Comment: When you say we can use different pages. Does that also mean that I can use mywebsite.com/dynamicobjectpage.php for all objects by feeding post/get data? Because I'm trying to do that and I keep running into trouble that one of my objects is already registered to it.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Maybe open a new question with code examples and examples of the error messages you're getting?